# p5.js - Fail to detect collision

Tags: javascript, collision, p5.js

So we have this code for checking collisions in p5js and it's not working.

We've already read all the answers related to this issue but clearly we are missing something and we can't see it.

This is the class:

```
class Cerchio_gen {
    constructor(x, y, speed, unit,raggio, color) { 
      this.x_ = x;
      this.y_ = y;
      this.Speed = speed;
      this.Unit = unit;
      this.XDir = 1;
      this.YDir = 1;
      this.Raggio = raggio/30;
      this.Color = color;
  
    }
   
    intersects(other){
      var d =p.dist (this.x_, this.y_, other.x_, other.y_);
      return d < this.Raggio + other.Raggio;
    }
    
    move(){
      this.x_ = this.x_ + this.Speed;
      if (this.x_ > 1240 || this.x_ < 10 ){
        this.Speed = - this.Speed;
      }

      if (this.y_ > 720 || this.y_ < 10)
        this.Speed = - this.Speed;
    }


    draw (){ 
      p.stroke(this.Color);
      p.circle(this.x_, this.y_, this.Raggio);
    } }
```

this is the setup function:

```
p.setup = function(){
    p.createCanvas(1240, 722);
    p.background('#272626');
    p.ellipseMode(p.CENTER);
    var wideCount = 1240 / unit;
    var highCount = 720 / unit;
    count = wideCount * highCount;
    p.noFill();
  
    var index = 0;
    for (var k = 0; k < 43; k++) {
      mods[index++] = new Cerchio_gen(
        150,
        150,
        p.random(100, 1200),
        p.random(100,600),
        p.random(0.1, 0.3),
        unit /2,
        ArrayGenere[k][0].nItem,
        ArrayColors[k]
      );
    }
     
  console.log (mods[0]);
  }
```

and this is the draw function:

```
p.draw = function() {
      p.clear();
      p.strokeWeight(4);
      for (var m of mods) {  
        m.move();   
        m.draw();

        var overlapping = false;
        for (var other of mods){
          if ( m != other && m.intersects(other)){
            ovelapping = true;
            // console.log("overlapping",overlapping);
            
          }
        }
        if (overlapping){
          m.Speed = -m.Speed;
          other.Speed = -other.Speed;
        }
       
      }
    }
```

Now I've edited the question so that you have the class. I will try to prepare a little working example and add it here when it's ready.

Comment: Could you maybe produce a [minimal working example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)? It is difficult to debug your code if you leave out class definition...

Comment: The problem could be that if x overlaps with y, then y overlaps also with x :) So you flip the speed of both x and y twice and thus you don't change it at all. -1 * -1 = 1

Comment: I guess you may have a point, but since I use the distance from point to point I'm not sure that the axis is relevant. We even added p.ellipseMode(p.CENTER); so that the distance is computed from the center of the circles.

Comment: This should work. Can't see why it's not. Malte is right, you should make a small example on jsfiddle or editor.p5js.org. We can see what's happening and sometimes (when creating a simplified example) you stumble upon the problem yourself. Also, why is this code written as an p5 instance? ;p unusual